# C++: read int from binaryfile

Tags: c++

I have pixels from an image which are stored in a binary file.

I would like to use a function to quickly read this file.

For the moment I have this:

```
std::vector<int> _data;    

std::ifstream file(_rgbFile.string(), std::ios_base::binary);
while (!file.eof())
{
    char singleByte[1];
    file.read(singleByte, 1);
    int b = singleByte[0];
    _data.push_back(b);
}
std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
file.close();
```

But on 4096 * 4096 * 3 images it already takes a little time.

Is it possible to optimize this function?

Comment: I wouldn't store bytes as int (which is at least 4 bytes long). Just allocate a `char` array (or std::vector, but call `reserve` before) with the size of data in the file (~50MB is not a big deal) and populate it in a single read. Then, you can do some processing of that array.

Comment: `int` isn't specific enough since it can have different sizes on different platforms. Your loop is also wrong. Read this: [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: You are reading one byte at a time and then making `int`s out of them. I doubt that' you've interpreted the file format correctly. What's stored in the file? RGBA?

Comment: why are readin byte by byte couldn't you load all the file in a dynamic array or line by line.

Comment: @pptaszni An `int` is at least 16 bits wide, not 4 bytes.

Comment: Files contain RGB tuples. I know that using `int` is  bad in this scenario. I was using `uint8_t` at first but I had some bugs with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make this faster by reading the whole file in one go, and preallocating the necessary storage in the vector beforehand:

```
std::ifstream file(_rgbFile.string(), std::ios_base::binary);
std::streampos posStart = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::streampos posEnd = file.tellg();
file.seekg(posStart);

std::vector<char> _data;
_data.resize(posEnd - posStart, 0);
file.read(&_data[0], posEnd - posStart);
std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
file.close();
```

#### Avoiding unnecessary i/o

By reading the file as a whole in one `read()` call you can avoid a lot of read calls, and buffering of the `ifstream`. If the file is very large and you don't want to load it all in memory at once, then you can load smaller chunks of maybe a few MB each.

Also you avoid lots of functions calls - by reading it byte-by-byte you need to issue `ifstream::read` 50'331'648 times!

#### vector preallocation

`std::vector` grows dynamically when you try to insert new elements but no space is left. Each time the vector resizes, it needs to allocate a new, larger, memory area and copy all current elements in the vector over to the new location.
Most vector implementions choose a growth factor between 1.5 - 2, so each time the vector needs to resize it'll be a 1.5-2x larger allocation.

This can be completely avoided by calling [`std::vector::reserve`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) or [`std::vector::resize`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/).
With these functions the vector memory only needs to be allocated once, with at least as many elements as you requested.

#### [Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/ro37EzdWq)

[Here's a godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/ro37EzdWq) that shows the performance improvement.

testing a ~5MB file (4096*4096*3 bytes)

- gcc 11.2, with optimizations disabled:

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| 1300ms | 16ms |

- gcc 11.2, `-O3`

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| 878ms | 13ms |

#### Small bug in the code

As @TedLyngmo has pointed out your code also contains a small bug.
The `EOF` marker will only be set once you tried to read **past** the end of the file. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

So the last read that sets the `EOF` bit didn't actually read a byte, so you have one more byte in your array that contains uninitialized garbage.

You could fix this by checking for `EOF` directly after the read:

```
while(true) {
    char singleByte[1];
    file.read(singleByte, 1);
    if(file.eof()) break;
    int b = singleByte[0];
    _data.push_back(b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. I'm not very familiar with C ++ yet.